# Web Scraping AccuWeather site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, pycharm

I have recently started learning Web scraping using Scrapy in python and am facing issues with scraping data from AccuWeather.org site (https://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/may-weather/328328?year=2020).
Basically I am capturing dates and its weather temperature for my reporting purpose.
When inspected the site I found too many div tags so getting confused to write the code. Hence thought I would seek experts help on this.

Here is my code for your reference.

```py
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['https://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/may-weather/328328?year=2020']

    def parse(self, response):
        All_div_tags = response.css('div.content-module')[0]
        #Grid_tag = All_div_tags.css('div.monthly-grid')
        Date_tag = All_div_tags.css('div.date::text').extract()
        yield {
            'Date' : Date_tag}
```

I wrote this in PyCharm and am getting error as "code is not handled or not allowed".
please could someone help me with this?

Comment: The Scrapy logs would be relevant here. Is there some redirection happening?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to read some websites that gave me the same error. It happens because some websites don't allow web scraping on them. To get data from these websites, you would probably need to use their API if they have one.
**Fortunately, AccuWeather has made it easy to use their API (unlike other APIs):**

1. You first need to create an account at their developers' website: https://developer.accuweather.com/
2. Now, create a new app by going to **My Apps** > **Add a new app**.
3. You will probably see some information about your app (if you don't, press its name and it will probably show up). The only information you will need is your **API Key**, which is essential for APIs.
4. AccuWeather has pretty good documentation about their API [here](https://developer.accuweather.com/apis), yet I will show you how to use the most useful ones. You will need to have the location key of the city you want to get the weather from, that is shown in the URL of its weather page, for example, London's URL is [www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather-forecast/328328](http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/london/ec4a-2/weather-forecast/328328), so its location key is 328328.
5. When you have the location key of the city/cities you want to get the weather from, open a file, and type:

```
import requests
import json
```

If you want the daily weather (as shown [here](https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-forecast-api/apis/get/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/%7BlocationKey%7D)), type:

```
response = requests.get(url="http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/LOCATIONKEY?apikey=APIKEY")
print(response.status_code)
```

Replacing APIKEY with your API key, and LOCATIONKEY with the city's location key. It should now display 200 when you run it (meaning the request was successful)
Now, load it as a JSON file:

```
response_json = json.loads(response.content)
```

And you can now get some information from it, such as the day's "definition":

```
print(response_json["Headline"]["Text"])
```

The minimum temperature:

```
min_temperature = response_json["DailyForecasts"][0]["Temperature"]["Minimum"]["Value"]
print(f"Minimum Temperature: {min_temperature}")
```

The maximum temperature

```
max_temperature = response_json["DailyForecasts"][0]["Temperature"]["Maximum"]["Value"]
print(f"Maximum Temperature: {max_temperature}")
```

The minimum temperature and maximum temperature with the unit:

```
min_temperature = str(response_json["DailyForecasts"][0]["Temperature"]["Minimum"]["Value"]) + response_json["DailyForecasts"][0]["Temperature"]["Minimum"]["Unit"]
print(f"Minimum Temperature: {min_temperature}")

max_temperature = str(response_json["DailyForecasts"][0]["Temperature"]["Maximum"]["Value"]) + response_json["DailyForecasts"][0]["Temperature"]["Maximum"]["Unit"]
print(f"Maximum Temperature: {max_temperature}")
```

And more.

If you have any questions, let me know. I hope I could help you!